# React to silent route change

Tags: angular

I use

```
 this.location.go(this.location.path() + '/search');
```

to add `/search` to my current path without triggering a reload.

Now I would like to react to this change. I have tried using

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => { console.log(event()}
```

But it seems that the route change is never detected. How can I react to adding `/search`?

Comment: The point of this trick is to change the URL without triggering any of the angular side effects, including router events... why do you want to do this? Maybe there's a better way.

Comment: where did you put your subscription code??